# Medium Pandas Panel to hdf5

Tags: python, pandas, panel, hdf5

I'm struggling with stupid problem; until now I was working with pandas panel that fits in to the memory. Now I've to scale up the process and I run out of the memory.
The solution proposed on the panda's documentation is to save everything on a hdf5 file. Well it works if your panel is smaller than the memory... otherwise it's impossible.
Here the code

```
import pandas as pd

store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5')

yrs = list(range(1999, 2014))
xsize = 15680
ysize = 40320

slPanel = pd.Panel(np.nan, items=yrs, major_axis=list(range(0, xsize)), minor_axis=list(range(0, ysize)))
store['SP'] = slPanel
```

Have you any ideas how to workaround this problem?
By the way I'm using python 3.5 x64 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this should work

To write to the file:

```
store = pd.HDFStore(‘test.h5’, ‘w’, append = True)
for partofpanel in panelparts:
  store.append('SP', partofpanel, data_columns = True, index = True)
```

To read from file:

```
x = pd.HDFStore(‘test.h5’, ‘r’)
for df in x.select(‘SP’, chunksize = 10):
   #Do some stuff
```

Separately, [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) may be your friend.

Comment: Hi Samuel, I already tested this option but there is something that doesn't work. I think that the problem is in the indexing system.   

 store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5', 'w', append=True)

yrs = list(range(1998, 2014))

xsize = 15680
ysize = 40320

for x, yr in enumerate(yrs):
        slPanel = pd.Panel(np.nan, items=list([yr]), major_axis=list(range(0, xsize)), minor_axis=list(range(0, ysize)))
        store.append('SP', slPanel, data_colums=True, index=True)

the output is:
 ValueError: cannot match existing table structure for [1998] on appending data

Comment: Hmm.  Without seeing the actual data, it's a bit hard for me to say what's going amiss.  It sounds like you have some type missmatch between the chunks you are trying to append.  Make sure all the elements in each column you append have the same type--this is something you can enforce when you read_csv.

When indexing is a problem, liberal use of .reset_index(drop=True) can sometimes be a quick fix...